# PCB design for MAX1709ESE

Tags: power, dc-dc-converter, boost, step-up

I am thinking of using MAX1709ESE step-up converter in my DIY project, and from [the datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1709.pdf) I have found that the chip is manufactured in SOIC16 case without a thermal pad (as opposed to MAX1709EUI+).
There is no PCB design example in the datasheet, and so I would like to ask if someone has any experience in creating a PCB with good power dissipation for chips without a thermal pad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the heat will come out of the leads, so you should try to have large areas of copper connected to the pins that are common with each other in particular.

Even though you don't have the EP package, look at the [MAX1709EVKIT](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX1709EVKIT.pdf) layout.

[image]

Try to have 0.5 to 1 inch² (total) copper areas connected directly to the pins, and pours on both sides of the PCB will help spread the heat.